# function Redirect in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I don't know how to use this function in laravel 5.2.

```
function Redirect($url, $permanent = false){
    if (headers_sent() === false){
        header('Location: ' . $url, true, ($permanent === true) ? 301 : 302);
    }
    exit();
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to use it.

Thanks

Comment: FatalErrorException in fa2ee1d3e95abd4ae729df2168ec83dd3bcc8c58.php line 10:
Cannot redeclare Redirect() (previously declared in D:\xampp\htdocs\n\qn76_code\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php:543)

Comment: That's useful information that should have obviously been included in your original post. The error message is quite clear: **Cannot redeclare Redirect()** The function name is already in use, so if you're adding your own `redirect()` function, you need to give it a *unique* name.

Answer (score 1):

Lets suppose you need to redirect to the url **/cats** from the controller. You can simply use redirect() global function as

```
Route::get('/redirect', 'CatController@returnRedirect');

//CatController

public function returnRedirect(){

       return redirect('/cats');

}
```

For more information, you can visit the [Laravel 5.2 Response](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses#redirects)